# web2py Validation

Tags: forms, web2py

I would like to know validation is a must, on fields which are not present on the form but are available in the table. Does marking them as NULL in the define_table make them validated only when they are present in the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [form validators](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07#Custom-forms) apply only to forms, so will not affect fields that are not present in the form. I'm not sure what you mean by marking a field as NULL, but if you are referring to `Field(..., notnull=True)`, that executes the SQL `NOT NULL` statement when the database table is first created (assuming DAL migrations are enabled). That option is enforced by the database itself whenever a record is inserted or updated (via a form or any other method). If a `notnull` field is left empty, it will result in an operational error from the database.